# LuaBridge running C++ main function in lua for Love2D

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

Here is my C++ main function :

```
int main() {
lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
getGlobalNamespace(L).
        beginNamespace("o").
            beginClass<Object>("Object").
                addConstructor<void (*) (double, double)>().
                addProperty("width", &Object::getWidth, &Object::setWidth).
                addProperty("height", &Object::getHeight, &Object::setHeight).
                addProperty("x", &Object::getX, &Object::setX).
                addProperty("y", &Object::getY, &Object::setY).
            endClass().
        endNamespace();
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
luaL_dofile(L, "main.lua");}
```

And here is my main.lua for Love2D

```
function love.load()
   obj = o.Object(10, 20) end
```

When i tried to run it with love it says that obj is a nil value and i realized that Love2D doesn't run my main function in C++ to create the object class.
How do i call a C++ main function in Lua using LuaBridge?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is using two separate programs: the one you build with your "main function", and the actual Love2D executable. They're *separate* executables; they have no more relation to one another than `lua.exe` has to `python.exe`.

What you appear to be *wanting* to do is write a C++ library that is *used by* Love2D. You can do that, but it requires that you write, not a C++ program, but a dynamic library. You have to write a Lua C-module.

How you write a dynamic library depends on your platform of choice. But that dynamic library must export the appropriate functions, as detailed in [the Lua 5.1 documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders). If your C module is named "test", then it must export a function called `luaopen_test`.

The job of this function is essentially what your `main` does. Your `luaopen_` function does not have to create a Lua state; it will be given one. It's job is to return a table that contains the functions and APIs you want to export in your module. So it registers everything with Lua as needed.

Your `main` puts its stuff in the global "namespace", but this is generally considered quite rude. It's better to build a local table and put your stuff there, returning the table as the return value. I'm not familiar with LuaBridge's API, so I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Worst case is that you could build a global table as you currently do, but after building it, load it into a local table, clear the global entry, then return the table.